# How to write a cell with multiple columns in xlwt?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'd like to write a table like this:

```
----------------
| Long Cell    |
----------------
| 1    | 2     |
----------------
```

How to write the cell `Long Cell`? Thanks.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
sheet.write(0, 0, 'Long Cell')
sheet.write(1, 0, 1)
sheet.write(1, 1, 2)
```

But it end up like:

```
--------------------
| Long Cell |      |
--------------------
| 1         | 2    |
--------------------
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this isn't documented - you have to read the source code to find it. There are two methods on the `Worksheet` class to do this, `write_merge` and `merge`. `merge` takes existing cells and merges them, while `write_merge` writes a label (just like `write`) and then does the same stuff `merge` does.

Both take the cells to merge as `r1, r2, c1, c2`, and accept an optional `style` parameter.

From your example, this would be the simplest call:

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 0, 1, 'Long Cell')
sheet.write(1, 0, 1)
sheet.write(1, 1, 2)
```

To be more explicit about how the call works:

```
top_row = 0
bottom_row = 0
left_column = 0
right_column = 1
sheet.write_merge(top_row, bottom_row, left_column, right_column, 'Long Cell')
```

Alternatively, using `merge`:

```
sheet.write(top_row, left_column, 'Long Cell')
sheet.merge(top_row, bottom_row, left_column, right_column)
```

`merge` has some comments in the source pointing out potential problems:

> ```
>     # Problems: (1) style to be used should be existing style of
>     # the top-left cell, not an arg.
>     # (2) should ensure that any previous data value in
>     # non-top-left cells is nobbled.
>     # Note: if a cell is set by a data record then later
>     # is referenced by a [MUL]BLANK record, Excel will blank
>     # out the cell on the screen, but OOo & Gnu will not
>     # blank it out. Need to do something better than writing
>     # multiple records. In the meantime, avoid this method and use
>     # write_merge() instead.
> ```

But it would be fine for a simple case like this.

Comment: Also there is a style argument like
sheet.write_merge(top_row, bottom_row, left_column, right_column, 'Long Cell', style)