# Merging more than two cells using xlwt python

Tags: python, excel, numpy, xlwt

I am trying to merge 4 columns in a row of an excel file. This link has some suggestions on how to do it for two rows: [How to write a cell with multiple columns in xlwt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672760/how-to-write-a-cell-with-multiple-columns-in-xlwt) 
The line it uses to merge two columns and two rows:

```
sheet.write_merge(0, 0, 0, 1, 'Long Cell')
```

However, the same code syntax does not work when i try to merge 4 rows only. My code:

```
sh.write_merge(0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,'Start point\nCo-ordinates')
```

I basically need something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIvyD.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this?

```
sh.write_merge(0, 0, 4, 7, 'Start point\nCo-ordinates')
```

Comment: Not working. That merges first 5 rows and first 8 columns. i just need to merge column 5,6,7 and 8 in the first row as shown in the image attached in my question !

Comment: @Eshant, my error, I edited the code accordingly. I had swaped r2 and c1. i.e. the order should be r1, r2, c1, c2. In your case r1=r2=0, c1=4, c2=7